# Comparing two attributes from journey data in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, attribute

when im comparing two attribute of number data type that are custom field in account, the decision split says "nullable fields cannot be compared. one of these two fields is nullable". I even tried comparing two text fields but then also it did not work

Comment: I think the error is self-explainatory. You must ensure to make the field required, in the data extension which holds the data evaluated in the decision split.

Comment: I created this custom field in salesforce and my marketing cloud is related to sales cloud. I made the fields Required but then also it was showing the same error. The data entry source for journey builder is salesforce data and not data extension

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue where that notification is displayed even when the compared fields are non-nullable: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KRe8QAG